# Using "AS" clause in SQL statement in alasql (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, sql, angularjs, export-to-excel, alasql

As the title describes, I have the problem, that I'm getting an error message as soon as I try to use the AS clause in the sql statement of the angular module [alasql](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/Getting-started).

The following error message will displayed:

> Error: Parse error on line 1: ... shortcode AS Short code, fname AS fullname
>   -----------------------^ Expecting 'EOF', 'WITH', 'COMMA', 'RPAR', 'PIVOT', 'UNPIVOT', 'REMOVE', 'ORDER', 'WHERE', 'UNION', 'INTERSECT',
>   'EXCEPT', 'FROM', 'INTO', 'GROUP', 'LIMIT', 'OFFSET', 'END', 'ELSE',
>   'SEMICOLON', 'GO', got 'LITERAL'

I'm not sure, what I'm doing wrong.
In the wiki, they also used the AS clause without problems.

My angular code is very simple as shown below:

```
vm.btnExport = function () {
   alasql('SELECT shortcode AS Short code, fname AS fullname INTO XLSX("test.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [vm.list]);
};
```

Comment: I don't beleive that this error is thrown for this piece of the code. You don't have any `as` keyword here

Comment: @smnbbrv sorry, I have edited my post. This error comes from the AS clause. Because as soon as I execute the code without AS clause, the function works.

Comment: @Jaco Do you know a better angular module for data exporting to excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most if not all databases do not allow spaces in table, column names or alias names. In Alasql use square brackets `[]`. So for your case you could rename `Short Code` to `Short_Code` or you could use `[Short Code]`. However... in Alasql there are a lot of keywords. So to be safe I put square brackets around everything that is not a keyword.

```
alasql('SELECT [shortcode] AS [Short code], [fname] AS [fullname] INTO XLSX("test.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [vm.list]);
```

Comment: Many thanks rick! It's very helpful :) Do you know how can I define the width of individual cells?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for my problem. It was the space character after the AS clause.

It's just allowed to define one word and not two.

Example:

```
vm.btnExport = function () {
   alasql('SELECT shortcode AS Short_Code, fname AS fullname INTO XLSX("test.xlsx",{headers:true}) FROM ?', [vm.list]);
};
```